# Visual studio web dev express hangs adding entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio

Im using VS express web developer, and attempting to create a new MVC project. The problem is, VS hangs when adding EntityFramework to the project. Its attempting to add EntityFramework 4.1.10331.0 to an MVC 3 project. Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: Does this happen if you create a new Empty ASP.NET MVC 3 project?

Answer (score 4):

It has been a while since you asked the question, but I recently stumbled across a similar issue except with MVC4 adding EntityFramework.5.0.0 in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.

The issue was that I was trying to create the project in a network folder (I run Windows 7 in a VM on top of OSX).

The problem appears to be that the network folder is not considered a Trusted Location. I had to go into Control Panel -> Internet Options, click "Security" tab, Click "Local Intranet" zone, then click Sites button.

In the "Local intranet" dialog which pops up, I un-checked "Automatically detect intranet network" and checked "Include all network paths (UNCs)"

Now I guess Visual Studio and/or nuGet see the network folder as a trusted location, and EntityFramework.5.0.0 is installed along with everything else a new MVC 4 project requires.

Credit goes to my colleague who referred me to [this SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/questions/44503/how-do-i-tell-windows-7-to-trust-a-particular-network-location).

Answer (score 0):

Bit of an old question, but it's still an issue today so this might help someone looking for a solution.

I don't have enough rep to comment on Chris Cameron's answer, so apologies for submitting it as a new answer - all credit should go to Chris.  I found that to get it working I also needed to check "Include all local (intranet) sites not listed in other zones."  Chris' solution then worked like a charm.